# Refer class from Module A to Module C through Module B gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

How can I refer my code from another module? I have a **Module A** which implements **Module B**. **Module B** implements **Module C** which contains classes that i need to access in **Module A**.

**Module A** contains class **Foo** {} and implements:

```
 dependencies {
    implementation project(":moduleB")
}
```

**Module B** implements:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":moduleC")
}
```

Module C contains Class **Bar** {}

I can easily access classes which are located in module BHow can i access class **Bar** {} (module C) from class **Foo** {} (module A)? Is there any way to achive this event in gradle?

Comment: what are the types of modules(lib or app) ... also why are you using `implementation` instead `api` if module type is lib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new `implementation` mechanics of importing dependencies hides dependencies 'downstream'. So if A depends on B and B depends on C, A **cannot** access C by default.
This was not the case with the old `compile` keyword, which has a successor in the `api` keyword, which probably is what you want. 
[This](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) and [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) should clear things up.

Answer (score 3):

As you have **moduleC** as a dependency in **moduleB**, it should be available in **moduleA** as this a **transitive** dependency

Make sure you have **transitive** set to **true** while adding **moduleB**
in **moduleA**